# How to prevent Cross-Site Scripting on form fields in Coldfusion 2016?

Tags: forms, validation, security, coldfusion, xss

Project using Coldfusion 2016 has a basic keyword search feature. Security scan produced a 'Cross-Site Scripting: Reflected' critical vulnerability. 'Hacker' could potentially inject scripts into the results page (ie: ) via the form field.

Should the form validation happen via javascript on the form page? Or once submitted, strip the input of any special characters like <>, etc? I need to modify the code for it to pass this security scan.

code:

```
<input type="text" name="keyword" value="search by keyword" onfocus="clearThis(this)" />
```

results page code:

```
<cfset input = "#form.keyword#">
<cfset keyword = rereplace(input,"[^A-Za-z0-9-]"," ","all") />
```

Thanks in advance-
HeatherG

Comment: Injecting scripts is one thing.  Getting them to execute is something else.  What are you doing with this variable once you have received it?

Comment: run a query to retrieve data that contains keyword.

Comment: Using `<cfqueryparam>` will alleviate your worries about the code executing.

Answer (score 1):

**AntiSamy Filter**

First, you have to scrub all user input using an [AntiSamy filter](https://owasp.org/www-project-antisamy/). CF ships with a default configuration file, but I can't find a reference to which it is. I recommend starting with the `antisamy-slashdot.xml` file [found here](https://github.com/nahsra/antisamy/tree/main/src/main/resources).

Load a specific config file in `Application.cfc` (reference the file from outside of the application's web root folder).

```
<cfset this.security.antisamypolicy = "antisamy-slashdot.xml">
```

Now you can use the native CF function [`getSafeHTML()`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/getsafehtml.html).

```
<cfset SafeHTML = getSafeHTML(inputHTML, "", true)>
```

The parameters are

1. The string to clean.
2. A specific config file. An empty string references the default or application-defined file.
3. `true` throws an error, `false` returns an empty string.

When I implemented this, I created a simple function to loop through a `struct` and clean all strings, then added it to my `Application.cfc`.

```
<cffunction name="getCleanStructData" access="public" output="false" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="data" type="struct" required="true" hint="Form struct">
        <cfloop collection="#arguments.data#" item="local.x">
            <cfif isSimpleValue(arguments.data[local.x])>
                <cfset arguments.data[local.x]=trim(getSafeHTML(arguments.data[local.x], "", ))>
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
</cffunction>
```

Finally, I added calls to that function in `onRequestStart()`:

```
<cfset getCleanStructData(form)>
<cfset getCleanStructData(URL)>
```

Now all user input data is cleaned according to the rules defined in the AntiSamy config file. You should be able to safely process this data as you see fit.

**Encoding User Input**

To further ensure your output is safe, you have to contextually call one of the ESAPI Encoding Functions when outputting user-generated data.

Old school CF only had `htmlEditFormat` and `JSStringFormat`. Since CF 10, there are newer functions like [`encodeForHTML()`](https://cfdocs.org/encodeforhtml) and `encodeForJavaScript()` that can escape the larger set of UTF-8 characters. This will convert strings into the appropriate HTML entities to display on a web page. For example:

```
#encodeForHTML('<script>')#
```

will render like this, stopping the linked file from being executed.

```
&lt;script&gt;
```

More info and examples here: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/

**Samy is My Hero**

Bonus: If you weren't in dev back when this worm ravaged MySpace, [here's how we learned XSS was a thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samy_(computer_worm)).